# PulseAudio occasionally no sound / chipmunk voice regardless of OS and microphone

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, microphone, mx-linux

**General problem:** I have been using Manjaro Mate 21.2.1 (Arch-based) with kernels 5.4, 5.10 and 5.13 for a while, until I got more and more sound problems using different softwares (Skype, Zoom, Browser-based conferencing programmes, OBS Studio, Audacity). I switched to MX Linux version MX-21 Wildflower yesterday, hoping that a fresh install would resolve the problems. Unfortunately, I still have the same problem as I did have before.

**Symptoms:** I am using a Logitech camera with integrated microphone. Pavucontrol does show me the microphone under the "Input Devices". Most of the time, the softwares metioned above do not record anything, but only show a soundless video (thus, the camera itself is working, but no sound). Sometimes I get a distorted Chipmunk-voice. And sometimes, with luck, the sound suddently works - without changing any settings whatsoever. And sometimes, when I e.g. do a test call in Skype and the sound works and when I call a person afterwards, the person cannot hear me. Some browsers tell me that they cannot detect the microphone. These symptoms appeared when I was using Manjaro and are still appearing while using MX Linux without any differences. In Pavucontrol, I cannot unlock the device (see screenshot below).

**When did it start?** I believe it started around December 2021 and is getting worse ever since.

**What did I try so far?**

- changing Distro to MX Linux
- reinstalling pulseaudio via: `sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio` and `sudo apt-get purge pavucontrol` and `rm -rf ~/.pulse/`
- rebooting endless times
- `pulseaudio -k` and `pulseaudio --start`
- `sudo chown -Rc $USER:$USER $HOME`
- reinstalling Skype, Zoom etc. and testing out all the packages available in the repo
- plugging out the camera, plugging in another different camera, plugging in headphones.
- (while using Manjaro, I also installed pulseaudio-alsa - I cannot see anything likewise in MX Linux repo)

The only thing that worked with luck was restarting the conference software and recalling the other person and / or `pulseaudio -k` and `pulseaudio --start`
(BTW: I also use the same Manjaro Mate version that I had before on another laptop with integrated microphone and camera and everything works fine.)

**Detailed information of my MX Linux:**

- neofetch (I only use Manjaro icons, please do not get confused, we are talking about the MX device here):

[image]

- Pavucontrol:

[image]

- with command `sudo aplay -l`, I get:

```
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 0: VT1708S Analog [VT1708S Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 3: VT1708S Digital [VT1708S Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

- with command `sudo aplay -L`, I get:

```
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
lavrate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Libav/FFmpeg Library
samplerate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Samplerate Library
speexrate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Speex Resampler
jack
    JACK Audio Connection Kit
oss
    Open Sound System
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
upmix
    Plugin for channel upmix (4,6,8)
vdownmix
    Plugin for channel downmix (stereo) with a simple spacialization
hw:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, VT1708S Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=SB,DEV=3
    HDA ATI SB, VT1708S Digital
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, VT1708S Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=SB,DEV=3
    HDA ATI SB, VT1708S Digital
    Hardware device with all software conversions
sysdefault:CARD=SB
    HDA ATI SB, VT1708S Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, VT1708S Analog
    Front output / input
surround21:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, VT1708S Analog
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, VT1708S Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, VT1708S Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, VT1708S Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, VT1708S Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, VT1708S Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
hdmi:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, VT1708S Digital
    HDMI Audio Output
dmix:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, VT1708S Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=SB,DEV=3
    HDA ATI SB, VT1708S Digital
    Direct sample mixing device
usbstream:CARD=SB
    HDA ATI SB
    USB Stream Output
hw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=3
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 0
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=3
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 0
    Hardware device with all software conversions
hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=0
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
dmix:CARD=HDMI,DEV=3
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 0
    Direct sample mixing device
usbstream:CARD=HDMI
    HDA ATI HDMI
    USB Stream Output
usbstream:CARD=U0x46d0x809
    USB Device 0x46d:0x809
    USB Stream Output
```

- with `pacmd list-cards`, I get:

```
3 card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_01_05.1>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 6
    properties:
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA ATI HDMI"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA ATI HDMI at 0xfeae8000 irq 19"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:05.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:05.1/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "1002"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"
        device.product.id = "960f"
        device.product.name = "RS780 HDMI Audio [Radeon 3000/3100 / HD 3200/3300]"
        device.string = "1"
        device.description = "RS780 HDMI Audio [Radeon 3000/3100 / HD 3200/3300]"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5900, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <off>
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
    index: 1
    name: <alsa_card.usb-046d_0809_FDC5DBAD-02>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.card = "2"
        alsa.card_name = "USB Device 0x46d:0x809"
        alsa.long_card_name = "USB Device 0x46d:0x809 at usb-0000:02:00.0-1, high speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:02:00.0-usb-0:1:1.2"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.2/sound/card2"
        udev.id = "usb-046d_0809_FDC5DBAD-02"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "046d"
        device.vendor.name = "Logitech, Inc."
        device.product.id = "0809"
        device.product.name = "Webcam Pro 9000"
        device.serial = "046d_0809_FDC5DBAD"
        device.form_factor = "webcam"
        device.string = "2"
        device.description = "Webcam Pro 9000"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "camera-web-usb"
    profiles:
        input:mono-fallback: Mono Input (priority 1, available: unknown)
        input:multichannel-input: Multichannel Input (priority 1, available: unknown)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <input:mono-fallback>
    sources:
        alsa_input.usb-046d_0809_FDC5DBAD-02.mono-fallback/#0: Webcam Pro 9000 Mono
    ports:
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
    index: 2
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_14.2>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 8
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA ATI SB"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA ATI SB at 0xfe8f4000 irq 16"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.2"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "1002"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"
        device.product.id = "4383"
        device.product.name = "SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (M4A785TD Motherboard)"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (priority 65, available: no)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (priority 6500, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (priority 6565, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-21: Analog Surround 2.1 Output (priority 1300, available: unknown)
        output:analog-surround-21+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 2.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 1365, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-40: Analog Surround 4.0 Output (priority 1200, available: unknown)
        output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 4.0 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 1265, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-41: Analog Surround 4.1 Output (priority 1300, available: unknown)
        output:analog-surround-41+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 4.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 1365, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-50: Analog Surround 5.0 Output (priority 1200, available: unknown)
        output:analog-surround-50+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 5.0 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 1265, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-51: Analog Surround 5.1 Output (priority 1300, available: unknown)
        output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 5.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 1365, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-71: Analog Surround 7.1 Output (priority 1200, available: unknown)
        output:analog-surround-71+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 7.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 1265, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5900, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5965, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <output:analog-stereo>
    sinks:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo/#0: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    sources:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo.monitor/#1: Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    ports:
        analog-input-front-mic: Front Microphone (priority 8500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-input-rear-mic: Rear Microphone (priority 8200, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-input-linein: Line In (priority 8100, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                
        analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
```

- with `pacmd list-sources`, I get:

```
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_input.usb-046d_0809_FDC5DBAD-02.mono-fallback>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE
    priority: 9040
    volume: mono: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 19944 /  30% / -31.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 1ch 48000Hz
    channel map: mono
                 Mono
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    card: 1 <alsa_card.usb-046d_0809_FDC5DBAD-02>
    module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "USB Audio"
        alsa.id = "USB Audio"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "2"
        alsa.card_name = "USB Device 0x46d:0x809"
        alsa.long_card_name = "USB Device 0x46d:0x809 at usb-0000:02:00.0-1, high speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:02:00.0-usb-0:1:1.2"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.2/sound/card2"
        udev.id = "usb-046d_0809_FDC5DBAD-02"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "046d"
        device.vendor.name = "Logitech, Inc."
        device.product.id = "0809"
        device.product.name = "Webcam Pro 9000"
        device.serial = "046d_0809_FDC5DBAD"
        device.form_factor = "webcam"
        device.string = "hw:2"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "192000"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "96000"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "mono-fallback"
        device.profile.description = "Mono"
        device.description = "Webcam Pro 9000 Mono"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "camera-web-usb"
    ports:
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
    active port: <analog-input-mic>
 - index: 1
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo.monitor>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE
    priority: 1030
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 1999.82 ms
    monitor_of: 0
    card: 2 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_14.2>
    module: 8
    properties:
        device.description = "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        device.class = "monitor"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA ATI SB"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA ATI SB at 0xfe8f4000 irq 16"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.2"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "1002"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"
        device.product.id = "4383"
        device.product.name = "SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (M4A785TD Motherboard)"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
```

- with `pacmd list-sinks`, I get:

```
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE
    priority: 9039
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 0 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 1
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 1999.82 ms
    card: 2 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_14.2>
    module: 8
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "VT1708S Analog"
        alsa.id = "VT1708S Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA ATI SB"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA ATI SB at 0xfe8f4000 irq 16"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.2"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "1002"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"
        device.product.id = "4383"
        device.product.name = "SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (M4A785TD Motherboard)"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "352768"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "176384"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    active port: <analog-output-lineout>
```

- with `pulseaudio -vvvv`, **I get an error**:

```
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NICE, (31, 31)) failed: Operation not permitted
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_RTPRIO, (9, 9)) failed: Operation not permitted
D: [pulseaudio] core-rtclock.c: Timer slack is set to 50 us.
I: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Failed to acquire high-priority scheduling: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: This is PulseAudio 14.2
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compilation CFLAGS: -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/pulseaudio-eJtUKc/pulseaudio-14.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -W -Wextra -pipe -Wno-long-long -Wno-overlength-strings -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations -Wundef -Wformat=2 -Wlogical-op -Wsign-compare -Wformat-security -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wformat-nonliteral -Wpointer-arith -Winit-self -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wfloat-equal -Wmissing-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-noreturn -Wshadow -Wendif-labels -Wcast-align -Wstrict-aliasing -Wwrite-strings -Wno-unused-parameter -fno-common -fdiagnostics-show-option -fdiagnostics-color=auto
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running on host: Linux x86_64 5.10.0-11-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.92-1 (2022-01-18)
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Found 6 CPUs.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Page size is 4096 bytes
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compiled with Valgrind support: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in valgrind mode: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in VM: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running from build tree: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Optimized build: yes
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: FASTPATH defined, only fast path asserts disabled.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Machine ID is 995013c2a2f4b36efda13e9561e972d6.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Session ID is 1.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using runtime directory /run/user/1000/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using state directory /home/X/.config/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using modules directory /usr/lib/pulse-14.2/modules.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode: no
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

```
X        3340    3328  0 16:13 ?        00:00:15 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/wrapper-2.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libpulseaudio-plugin.so 5 29360138 pulseaudio PulseAudio Plugin Adjust the audio volume of the PulseAudio sound system
X       45361       1  0 20:06 ?        00:00:03 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
X       49158   47280  0 20:19 pts/1    00:00:00 grep pulse
```

By launching audacity in terminal, it gives this **error**:

```
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card 'Camera'
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such device
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such device
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
```

and

```
*** BUG ***
In pixman_region32_init_rect: Invalid rectangle passed
Set a breakpoint on '_pixman_log_error' to debug

21:55:10: Debug: AudioIO::GetBestRate() for playback
21:55:10: Debug: GetBestRate() suggested rate 44100 Hz
21:55:10: Debug: GetBestRate() Returning 44100 Hz
```

I also noticed by recording with audacity while speaking and while playing music on the same pc, that audacity is only able to record the music (thus the internal sound), but not my voice (the external sound).

Please let me know in the comments if you need more information. I am willing to provide anything.